# How to send Email using Node JS from multiple accounts?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, nodemailer

I'm building a system, where its registered users are able to send emails automatically. I came across 2 solutions to achieve this,

1. By getting the username and password of GMAIL accounts and sending mails using nodemailer.
2. By using Google Oauth, to let the users give access to my app to send mails on their behalf(Without sharing their mail credentials).

The first method works as a piece of cake, but the second option sounds a bit more professional and safe. I figured out how to send mail using a single acc. to other people. But couldn't find a possible solution, to send emails from the user's mail. (As it requires refresh token to send them)

I came here looking up for a possible solution that helps me solve this issue.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go with google OAuth or if using first one use bcrypt salt or some type of hashing to secure password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but by hashing the password and saving it in the DB, is it possible to decode it back for further mail transactions?

Comment: Yes try this docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt. I personally use it and it stores you data in hash format in data and when you want to verfy password just use bcrypt.comapre(notHashed, hashed).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for `second option`. There is a good and very important reason to do so. You need to have a good and secure DB to save this information which could be an overhead for you.

Hashing the password and saving it to the DB won't help you. As you can never get the actual password from the hashed one and you can't send the hashed password to the gmail account. So, you can't do that.

Second option is a better way in every term, you just need to have a refresh token and that won't be a big deal. You can get it nodemailer transport layer can help you to get it.

I am attaching this [link](https://dev.to/chandrapantachhetri/sending-emails-securely-using-node-js-nodemailer-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-g3a#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Creating%20OAuth%202.0%20API%20Credentials&text=A%20client%20id%20identifies%20our,securely%20send%20emails%20from%20Nodemailer.&text=After%20clicking%20create%20credentials%2C%20a,to%20configure%20the%20consent%20screen.) where you can easily replicate the steps to get it done.